# How to track dependencies when a reported bug affects multiple products containing shared components?

Tags: issue-tracking, dependency-analysis

If you have multiple products that contain some shared components, how do you track dependencies to work out which other products a bug affects?

For example, product A, B and C use a CRC library module. A bug is found and filed in the module in product A. How can we assess that B and C are affected and need a bug fix release.

Of course we already have version control and issue tracking software, but it's not clear whether or how they can help in doing this, or whether we need to look for better tools.

Practically, is it worth modeling a subsystem breakdown to detect that an issue/defect affects also other products?

Comment: What we do is analyse branches in our VCS to work out which products are affected by check-ins. It produces false positives, but not false negatives.